# Is there a site for browsing a ton of photographers by location and skillset?

Tags: web, photographer

I'm looking to hire a photographer for a tech / fashion shoot in NYC.  I'm very particular on the style that I'm looking for and I'm hoping someone here can point me to a site where I can do some research on photographers portfolios

I'd like to browse photographers in my area and hire someone in the next week or so, but I cannot find a good website to help me.

Comment: This would surprise me, tbh.  As a working (albeit newly) photographer, I wouldn't submit my portfolio to an aggregation site.  I lose my 'brand' and image from my website mainly.

Answer (score 2):

The Professional Photographers of America maintains a "Find a Photographer" directory of its members: http://www.ppa.com/findaphotographer/

The American Society of Media Photographers also maintains a similar directory: http://asmp.org/find-a-photographer

Both directories allow members to post some representative images and both organizations are established professional organizations with a long history in the industry.